# How to land the user on a different page while using AutoTabsScaffold and BottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I'm using Auto_Route for routing in my application and AutoTabsScaffold makes it easier. But by default, the user is navigated to the first page in the bottom navigation bar but I want it to be navigated to third page by default. How can I do that?

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
AutoTabsScaffold(
        routes: [
          A(),
          B(),
          C(),
          D(),
          E(),
        ],
        bottomNavigationBuilder: (_, tabsRouter) {
          return BottomNavigationBar(
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            selectedItemColor: const Color(0XFFEAF8FF),
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
            currentIndex: tabsRouter.activeIndex,
            onTap: tabsRouter.setActiveIndex,
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.groups_outlined), label: ""),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search), label: ""),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.catching_pokemon), label: ""),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.library_add_check_outlined), label: ""),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline), label: ""),
            ],
          );
```

I want the user to land on C() and not A(). How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was able to find the answer, there is an option called "initial" that can be set to true while using auto_route and it will do the job. Thanks anyway.

Comment: There is `homeIndex` attribute where you can put the index of screen from array.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue.
I use auto_route package in my project.
We can see that current index depend on `tabsRouter.activeIndex` property.
So, I just added to the preferred route `initial: true,` property.

Like this:

```
 CustomRoute(
  path: '/',
  page: MainScreen,
  name: 'MainScreenRoute',
  guards: [AuthGuard],
  transitionsBuilder: TransitionsBuilders.fadeIn,
  children: [
    AutoRoute(
      path: 'wallet',
      page: WalletScreen,
    ),
    AutoRoute(
      path: 'trades',
      page: TradesScreen,
    ),
    AutoRoute(
      path: 'market',
      initial: true,
      page: MarketScreen,
    ),
```